# How can kernel run all the time?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, scheduling

How can kernel run all the time, when CPU can execute only one process at a time ?
That is, if kernel is occupying CPU all the time , then how come other processes run.

Please explain
Thank You

Comment: It doesn't run all the time.  The kernel sets an alarm interrupt for the CPU to wake it up every so often, then when the alarm interrupt fires the CPU stops executing the program and jumps to the kernel's interrupt vector.  When the CPU starts executing the kernel, the kernel checks if it should shelve the program the CPU was executing (if there is something higher priority) or if it should just go back to sleep and let the CPU keep executing the program that was already running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same way that you can run multiple userspace processes at the same time: Only one of them is actually using the CPU at any given time. You have some interrupts that force them to give it up.

Code that is part of the operating system is no different here (except that it is in control of setting up this scheduling in the first place).

You also have to distinguish between processes run by the OS in the background (I suppose that is what you are talking about here), and system calls (which are being run as part of "normal" processes that temporarily switch into supervisor mode).