# What does the kernel do while another process is running

Tags: operating-system, kernel, scheduling

Consider this: When one task/process is running on a single processor system, another task has to wait for its turn till the first task is either suspended or terminates (depending on the scheduling algorithm).
Kernel also consists of various tasks that are using the using the same CPU to do OS related stuff - like scheduling, memory management, responding to system calls etc.

So when a kernel schedules a particular task/process to give it CPU time, does it relinquish its control over the CPU?ie does it momentarily stop? If not how does it continually keep on running to do all OS related tasks while the other process is running on CPU? Does the scheduler move aside to give the next task in line CPU and if so what brings the scheduler back to go on with further scheduling activities? This question is similar but it does not contain enough details -
[How can kernel run all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006604/how-can-kernel-run-all-the-time)

I am confused about this part and I cant understand how this would work.Can somebody please explain this in detail. It would be helpful if you could explain it with an example.

Comment: How much do you know about interrupts? (if you know even a bit, just thinking about it will probably answer all your questions)

Comment: Depends on the CPU. A single-core, single-thread CPU won't do anything at all.

Comment: dont think kernel is always running on processor; when needed it is called through interrurpts. Interrupts call specific routine of the kernel so at that time you can say kernel is running

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah.. you should stop thinking of the OS kernel as a process and think of it instead of just code and data - a state-machine that processes/threads call in to in order to obtain specific services at one end, (eg. I/O requests) and drivers call in to at the other end to provide service solutions, (eg. I/O completion).

The kernel does not need any threads of execution in itself.  It only runs when entered from syscalls, (interrupt-like calls from running user threads/processes),  or drivers, (hardware interrupts from disk/NIC/KB/mouse etc hardware).  Sometimes, such calls will change the set of threads running on the available cores, (eg. if a thread waiting for a network buffer becomes ready because the NIC driver has completed the action, the OS will probably try to assign it to a core 'immediately', preempting some other thread if required).

If there are no syscalls, and no hardware interrupts, the kernel does nothing because it is not entered -  there is nothing for it to do.

Comment: Lmao I liked how you start the answer with "yeah..." :) Incredible answer

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is that few operating systems these days have a monitor process as you are describing.

At the risk of gross oversimplification, operating systems run through exceptions and interrupts.

Assume you have two processes, P and Q. P is the running process and Q is the next to run. One way to switch processes is the system timer goes off triggering an interrupt. P switches to kernel mode and handles that interrupt. P runs the interrupt code handling the timer and determines that Q should run. P then saves its context and loads Q. At that moment, Q is the running process. The interrupt handler exits and picks up where Q was before.

In other words, process P becomes the kernel scheduler while the interrupt is being processed. Each process becomes the scheduler that loads the next process.

Another example, let us say that Q has queued a read operation to a disk. That operation completes and triggers an interrupt. P, the running process, enters kernel mode to handle the interrupt. P then processes Q's disk read operation.